# В Dockerfile не работает ARG для FROM

Tags: docker, dockerfile, devops, непрерывная-интеграция, docker-build

`docker info`:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:    24.0.7
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
 Plugins:
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.11.2
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.21.0
    Path:     /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

Server:
 Containers: 15
  Running: 1
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 14
 Images: 339
 Server Version: 24.0.7
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Using metacopy: false
  Native Overlay Diff: true
  userxattr: false
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Cgroup Version: 1
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 3dd1e886e55dd695541fdcd67420c2888645a495
 runc version: v1.1.10-0-g18a0cb0
 init version: de40ad0
 Security Options:
  apparmor
  seccomp
   Profile: builtin
 Kernel Version: 5.4.0-132-generic
 Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 3.839GiB
 Name: ubuntu-2004-clean-01
 ID: e397e021-a07f-4d31-8542-a4a52e25c357
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode: false
 Experimental: false
 Insecure Registries:
  172.16.11.200:5000
  cache.localdomain:5000
  repo.localdomain:5000
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Часть `Dockerfile`:

```
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS="cache.localdomain:5000"
ARG DISTRO=alpine
ARG DISTRO_VERSION=3.18
ARG DOCKER_NODEJS_IMAGE_NAME=${DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS}/node-${DISTRO}${DISTRO_VERSION}

FROM ${DOCKER_NODEJS_IMAGE_NAME} AS nodejs
```

Выполняю `docker build . --tag image-custom` и получаю:

`ERROR: failed to solve: base name (${DOCKER_NODEJS_IMAGE_NAME}) should not be blank`

В разных сетях планирую использовать разные адреса реестра докер-образов и разные имена самих докер образов. Поэтому пишу `ARG`, чтобы можно было делать `docker build --build-arg`.

Comment: Что-то вы не договариваете. Я взял ваш `Dockerfile`, запустил `docker build .` и получил ошибку `Get "https://cache.localdomain:5000/v2/": dial tcp: lookup cache.localdomain on [xxx]:53: no such host`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, `localdomain` - как бы намекает, что адрес - внутри сети и недоступен из вне. У меня на этом адресе крутится https://hub.docker.com/_/registry, в котором опубликованы несколько контейнеров. В том числе и `nodejs` на alpine. Для внешнего использования, можно заменить на дефолтный, а именно `ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS="docker.io"`. Могу исправить вопрос, хотя мне показалось это очевидным.

Comment: То что домен не откроется это очевидно. Я про то что переменная вполне себе не пустая, так что ваша ошибка (`... should not be blank`) не воспроизводится. А значит вы запускаете что-то не так как написано в вопросе.

Comment: Ну вы можете у себя поменять строку на `ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS="docker.io"` и проверить?

Comment: Так. У меня чё-то начало работать. Отпишусь тогда о результате.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл проблему.

У меня слишком высоко был `LABEL maintainer=${MAINTAINER}`, которому уже нужен был какой-то образ, поэтому, в качестве временного решения в самое начало файла был добавлен `FROM alpine`. Т.е. более п**о**лно выглядело так:

```
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS="cache.localdomain:5000"
ARG DISTRO=alpine
ARG DISTRO_VERSION=3.18
FROM ${DISTRO}

ARG DOCKER_NODEJS_IMAGE_NAME=${DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS}/node-${DISTRO}${DISTRO_VERSION}

ARG MAINTAINER="don Rumata"
LABEL maintainer=${MAINTAINER}

FROM ${DOCKER_NODEJS_IMAGE_NAME} AS nodejs
```

Судя по всему, я нарушил порядок создания слоёв и поэтому всё крашилось. Вот правильный вариант:

```
ARG DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS="cache.localdomain:5000"
ARG DISTRO=alpine
ARG DISTRO_VERSION=3.18

ARG DOCKER_NODEJS_IMAGE_NAME=${DOCKER_REGISTRY_ADDRESS}/node-${DISTRO}${DISTRO_VERSION}

FROM ${DOCKER_NODEJS_IMAGE_NAME} AS nodejs

ARG MAINTAINER="don Rumata"
LABEL maintainer=${MAINTAINER}
```